# C++ equivalent of Java's Linked List / C#'s Array List?

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop, arraylist

Is there an STL container or something else that gives the same functionality as Java's Linked List or C#'s Array List? i.e appending different types into the same array like

```
List.Append(1);
List.Append("I am a string");
List.Append(True);
```

and dynamic functions like

```
List.Resize();
List.GetSize();
```

etc.?

If not , can u implement one yourself using templates etc.? If so, How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to implement this using templates because templates assume a single type for members. In C++ you'll have to use polymorphism with a common source (which is available in Java and C# as a common "Object" parent for all the classes, IMHO).

You can try to do it using the boost library, and the `boost::variant` or `boost::any` ([choose which one fits your needs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any)).

Comment: Or some sort of Variant class

Comment: ok so let's say i have a set of objects all inherited from the same base class. If i use runtime polymorphism i'll be able to add all to a single array using base class pointers. But then won't they only be able to perform methods defined in the base class and not their own methods?

Comment: @burningprodigy - yes, if you use run time polymorphism that will be your limitation. You can use `dynamic_cast` to switch types, but it's kindof ugly. What is the underlying need?

Comment: @littleadv An rpg tile engine. **tiles[i].image = spriteset[i].image** all the sprites have been inherited from the **sprite** base class. But i can't pack them into the spriteset[] array

Comment: @burningprodigy: how is that situation different from the C#/Java examples you quoted?

Comment: @burningprodigy: oh my, why do you need tiles to have different classes? Do they have such radically different behavior?

Comment: @jalf The **tiles[]** is not the problem, it's the **spriteset[]**. I need tiles to have different classes because each has a different function. Some are people which move around, some are houses. Some are coins which disappear when you collide them etc.

Comment: @burningprodigy: If all of them are tiles, then they should have the same type. There can be sub-types of tiles, but you don't need them to be actual C++ _types_ to have sub-types. Just have an enumeration that defines whether it is a "coin", "person", etc.

Comment: But all these tiles have a common base type, don't they? So can't you use a C++ std::vector of that type?

Comment: Sure, those game entities need different functionality and will have to be treated specially (which leads to the question, why do you need to store them in the same array?). But the *sprites*? Why would you *ever* need more than one sprite class? A sprite has one simple function: it's a 2d image that can be rendered at a position on the screen. It doesn't matter whether that image shows a coin, a person or the Hindenburg, does it?

Comment: @jalf Oh now i see what was doing wrong, I was putting the game functionality in the same class I use to render the sprites. I should create a gameobject class and put a sprite object _inside_ the class , not inherit from it.

Answer (score 6):

First off, `ArrayList` in C# and `LinkedList` in Java are fundamentally different beasts (one implements a resizable array while the other implements a linked list).

Secondly, `ArrayList` in C# (but not in Java) is deprecated; use the generic `List<T>` instead (in your case, a `List<object>`).

Thirdly, this corresponds to [`std::vector`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/) in C++.

If you need to insert different types into it, you got three basic choices:

- Use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html)
- Use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html)
- Use a common base class. This is the most sensible alternative in 95% of the cases.

Comment: "Use a common base class."                                        Plz see my comment on littleadv's answer.

Comment: @burningprodigy So what’s the problem then? If you have a common base class `Sprite` then simply use a vector of sprite pointers. The problems you get (not able to call child class methods) is *the same* that you’ve got in C# and Java, and shows a flaw in your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any.html) and then a std::list.
Take a look at the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) of the boost homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine std::list with boost.Variant as type T.

Answer (score 0):

Java/C# manage this by having an Object class that all classes derive from. C++ does not have this root.

If all your data is in a class hierarchy then you can use a std::list or vector of pointers (bare or smart) to the root class.

If not then you need to use an adaptor to make them appear the same class e.g. [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/variant.html) and then make a list of those. e.g. `std::list<boost::variant>`